# ¿Como hacer "rules" reactivas en quasar?

Tags: vue.js, programación-reactiva, quasar

Estoy tratando de crear un q-input con una mensaje que puede cambiar pero no es reactivo, en el siguiente codigo verán que solo se actualiza al momento de modificar el q-input pero no al momento de presionar el botón

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#q-app',
  data () {
    return {
      model: '',
      counter: 1
    }
  },

  methods: {
    reset () {
      this.$refs.input.resetValidation()
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.$refs.input.validate()
  }
})
```

```css
#marg {
padding:50px
}
body {
  background-color: white
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <!--
    WARNING! Make sure that you match all Quasar related
    tags to the same version! (Below it's "@1.14.0")
  -->

  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@1.14.0/dist/quasar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Add the following at the end of your body tag -->
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@^2.0.0/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@1.14.0/dist/quasar.umd.min.js"></script>
<div id="q-app">
  <div class="column q-gutter-md q-pa-md" style="max-width: 400px">
    <q-input
      ref="input"
      filled
      v-model="model"
      :rules="[
          val => (!!val && val.length < 2) || `El contador es ${counter}`,
        ]"
      lazy-rules
    ></q-input>

    <div>El contador es {{ counter }}</div>
    <q-btn label="Incrementar" @click="counter++" color="primary"></q-btn>
    <q-btn label="Resetear Validación" @click="reset" color="secondary"></q-btn>
    <div>Quasar {{ $q.version }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

He probado colocar el mensaje mensaje pero no pasó nada, tambien he tratado de jugar con la propiedad lazy-rules y tampoco he tenido suerte

¿Alguna forma de hacer reactivo el rule?, muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Sin tener el 100% claro de lo que necesitas hacer el unico problema que veo en porque tu contador no es reactivo es porque estas llamando v-model 'model' cuando deberia ser 'counter'

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#q-app',
  data () {
    return {
      model: '',
      counter: 1
    }
  },

  methods: {
    reset () {
      this.$refs.input.resetValidation()
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.$refs.input.validate()
  }
})
```

```css
#marg {
padding:50px
}
body {
  background-color: white
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <!--
    WARNING! Make sure that you match all Quasar related
    tags to the same version! (Below it's "@1.14.0")
  -->

  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@1.14.0/dist/quasar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Add the following at the end of your body tag -->
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@^2.0.0/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@1.14.0/dist/quasar.umd.min.js"></script>
<div id="q-app">
  <div class="column q-gutter-md q-pa-md" style="max-width: 400px">
    <q-input
      ref="input"
      filled
      v-model="counter"
      :rules="[
          val => (!!val && val.length < 2) || `El contador es ${counter}`,
        ]"
      lazy-rules
    ></q-input>

    <div>El contador es {{ counter }}</div>
    <q-btn label="Incrementar" @click="counter++" color="primary"></q-btn>
    <q-btn label="Resetear Validación" @click="reset" color="secondary"></q-btn>
    <div>Quasar {{ $q.version }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Favor aclarar si era lo que necesitabas realizar.